# ActiveRecord multiple databases without Rails

Tags: activerecord

I would like to use ActiveRecord in a project without Rails.
I would also like to specify the database connections in config/database.yml like Rails does.

There is already one answer how multiple database connections work with Rails.
[ActiveRecord talk to two databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609482/activerecord-talk-to-two-databases)

I was unsuccessful using this approach and I'm not sure why. I only get the error message "database configuration does not specify adapter".

Is there some kind of magic in Rails that reads the database.yml that is not in ActiveRecord?
I could read it myself but then I don't know how to feed it to ActiveRecord so that I can use establish_connection in each model.

Answer (score 2):

I found out how it works. You just fill the ActiveRecord::Base.configurations hash and then it works.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/configurations/class

Comment: any code example?