# Merge two database with same structure created over year keeping IDs and relations in mind - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have 3 to 4 databases of one single rails application modified over years and archived over years of data.

I now wanted to merge all those databases into one database but also need to make sure that the ids and relation of tables maintained.

Is there any way to merge without worries or I have to go through each and every merge records and maintain the relationships.

e.g. I have DB1-2011 & DB1-2012
Say Programs table has same structure, column might change in 2012, but not a big deal. 
But It might happen that DB1-2011.programs have id 5 and related records & DB1-2012.programs also has record with id 5

So here how I can manage this situation without worrying. Is there any way where MySQL / Rails / any other software can change / auto increment the other id and update in related records as well? If not then what will be a best way to do this.

Let me know if any more info needed.

Comment: Any useful answer to this question would be entirely schema-dependent. But you haven't furnished a schema, so it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unenviable task ahead of you, so far as I can tell. If you have a reasonably small number of table relationships, I would take the following approach:

- Take multiple, recoverable backups of all data. Make sure you know how to restore these. Don't proceed further until that's a certainty.
- Decide which app is going to be your canonical instance going forward
- Create connections to the other databases, using a technique [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609482/activerecord-talk-to-two-databases)
- Devise a series of migrations, that will run on your canonical instance, that iterate over those connections and `create!` entities anew in your canonical DB. You'll create, for example, `Program` instances, and then the associated objects. They will be given new, consistent with canonical, identifiers, and the rest of the data will be brought forward intact.

You'll need to be super careful about remembering all relationships, and applying the iteration in a sane order, which is why I would only do this if you have a cognitively-manageable number of tables and relationships.

Good luck!

Comment: Thats how I thought to doing so but wanted to check if there is any other way which I can use at the database level itself

Comment: @BhushanAhire If there is a database-level way, I'm not aware of it. It's a pretty bad idea, generally speaking, for primary keys to change, so it's not the type of operation that would make sense for a database to support. It's therefore up to you to do an ETLish operation to end up in the state you need.